# .tableSorterPager is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

I getting the following error:

```
.tableSorterPager is not a function.
```

I can't find my mistake in the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("table")
        .tableSorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tableSorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the tablesorter plugin before you run this code? Mayber you could show us your markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means the tableSorterPager plugin was not initialized before you called it.

Possible reasons:

1. You forgot to include the tableSorter.pager.js file in your page (`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>`).  tableSorter pager is a *separte* plugin to tableSorter.
2. You included tableSorter.js *after* you made the call to it.  Don't forget, javascript is evaluated in the order it appears on the page
3. You have a namespace conflict between two plugins